# Xcode linker problems multiple files Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker

I usually work a lot with Objective-C and sometimes I do have multiple files that represent multiple classes.

Sometimes program run and sometimes I get this error:

> linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What is the reason for this error? There were different solutions reported in the forum but I want to understand what is the reason to avoid.

Comment: the reason cause this type problem is too board. look at there:http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338712/could-i-ask-about-possible-causes-for-an-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea of compiling a program consists of separately compiling each file, and then linking the compiled binaries together. When it says linker command failed it means linking the binaries failed. What the linker error is depends on what the error says. Usually inside the junk there are a couple useful lines that can help you figure out what the issue is. A couple that comes to mind is when a function is defined twice, when a function is called but isn't declared anywhere, or when you import a library that contains a main function (which means main is defined twice) etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possible reasons behind this. I list some of those that I experienced.

1. You accidentally imported a .m file inside a .m file.
2. The libraries you linked have the same class name and it will cause a conflict.
3. The libraries you linked are built with different settings(e.g. the target iOS version, code signing, etc.)
4. The libraries you linked are built for simulator then you used it on a real device.
5. You forgot to put a semicolon in the end of a declaration in Localizable.strings